# Trouble with second class

Tags: java

I have tried to create two classes. But something went wrong. The first class works well, but the second works bad. Here's my code.

```
 public class Test {
 String name;

 public class Programmers {
String programmerName;
  int ageProgrammer;
 int quantityOfChildren;
 }
```

So, and implementation of the second class.

```
Programmers Tagir = new Programmers();
Tagir.ageProgrammer = 1300;
Tagir.programmerName = "Tagirix";
Tagir.quantityOfChildren = 10;
```

Unfortunately, the Eclipse has showed a trouble with `new Programmers();`. But I don't know what did it mean. What do I should do?

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: what is issue that Eclipse has reported?

Comment: please share full code

Comment: variable names in java start with a lower case letter.

Comment: You need another `}` somewhere, I think.  Maybe after the definition of the `Test` class would be a good place.

Comment: @SampritiPanda - are you sure you didn't just edit the question into oblivion?

Comment: @SampritiPanda - I rolled back your edit, which essentially fixed the problem the OP was having. Although this would be useful in an answer, it causes confusion for new readers, who cannot immediately see any problem with the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an instance of class Test first.

1. Test test = new Test();
2. change Programmers Tagir = new Programmers();
   to 
   Programmers Tagir = **test.new Programmers();**

Comment: This must be correct.  If the missing `}` went where the helpful editor has put it, there'd be an error from having two public classes in the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing these two classes in separate files. I had this issue before. We cant use more than one public class in one file. Not sure what the reason is though.

Comment: This rule is part of Java, not just Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a mistake in your code, you can't declare two public class in same file but you can define public class as nested class.

If it is a eclipse problem then you can try the following

**Eclipse Trick**

1. Uncheck Build automatically from Project menu, now clean your project by choosing the clean menu from Project menu.
2. Start your eclipse with -clean switch

e.g.

```
E:\eclipse-jee-kepler-RC3-win32\eclipse.exe -clean
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What appears is you have a missing Currly brace in your snippet, if it was at the end , then Programmers becomes an inner class an cannot be instantiated without an outer object  attached to it,

```
Test.Programmers Tagir = new Test().new Programmers();
```